# Reorder elements on mouse over (to solve Z-index conflict) when data is bound through `selectAll.data(data)`

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a d3 plot, where I have multiple elements which might overlap when drawn.

Each element renders a timeline and has multiple graphical units (start circle, line and end circle), something like as below:

```
O----------O     O
       O--------------------O
      O-------O-----O-------O
```

For example the third line has two timeline plot elements which are overlapping as start time of the 2nd timeline is before end time of the first timeline. Note that 2nd timeline in the first line has only start time (as end time and start time are same).

Now, the following code brings an element of the timeline to front on mouseover by moving the DOM node to be the last child of its parent.

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
    return this.each(function(){
   this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};
```

But the problem is that this is not altering the order of the bound data and is breaking the overall plot.

Each of the plot element has specific order in the dom which is bound to the d3 data in the same order. When the code above changes the order to bring any element to the front it is breaking the order, it still thinks that the order of the children are the same, which is wrong.

Here is a sample JSFiddle to describe the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/g2gt1f03/57/

How can I retain the data order once I have altered the dom elements?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing the html update by yourself let d3 do it, remember that d3 stands for **data driven documents** so rewrite your problem as

> On mouseover move the selection's datum to the last position and then rerender the graph

Imagine that your data is `[0,1,2,3]`, when you mouseover on any element that represents the second datum you move the second datum to the last position i.e. `[0,2,3,1]` and that's pretty much it

```
.on("mouseover", function() {
  var selection = d3.select(this);
  var d = selection.datum()

  // find d in data, extract it and push it
  var index = data.indexOf(d)
  var extract = data.splice(index, 1)
  data = data.concat(extract)
  draw()
});
```

Next when you bind your data make sure you add a way to distinguish from both states which is done with the second parameter sent to the `.data()` function which might be an id

```
var data = [
  [5, 8, 6],
  [10, 10, 6],
  [20, 25, 6],
  [23, 27, 6]
].map(function (d, i) {
    return {
    id: i,
    x1: d[0],
    y1: d[2],
    x2: d[1],
    y2: d[2]
  }
});
// ...
var itemGroup = maingroup.selectAll(".itemGroup")
  .data(data, function (d) { return d.id })
```

Finally you'll need to tell d3 that we have modified the order of the elements and that it needs to do what you were doing by hand which is reorder the elements

```
// update
itemGroup.order()
```

#### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g2gt1f03/59/)

Comment: That's awesome. However, I may have already fixed the issue using second parameter in data(). I have added a key property in the data element. And using the key while binding the data, data(dataArray, key).
It looks like updating the plot element with correct key data.

Answer (score 1):

I like the way Mauricio solved the issue.

However, after some investigation I came to know that I can specify key value while binding the data. So here is my solution without re-ordering the data itself:

1. I added a key value property for each data object which is unique.
2. I specify the key value while binding the data like,

   data(data_list, funcion(d){return d.keyValue})

the problem was fixed.